# Python PIL open image from specific file

Tags: python, operating-system, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I'm getting to grips with the Pillow library from Python. I have a folder (folder 1) where the code is stored and within that folder another folder (folder 2) where all the pictures I would like to edit/manipulate are.

However, I have only been able to access the images when they are saved in folder 1, but not when they are only saved in folder 2.

I have used the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

for k in os.listdir('.'):
    if k.endswith('.jpg'):
        i = Image.open(k)
        kn, kext = os.path.splitext(k)
        print(kn)
```

Which prints the names of all the file names minus the '.jpg' extension:

```
MeisJeMetDeParel
StarryNight
TheSonOfMan
```

I have then tried to do the same, only accessing the images from inside their own specific folder:

```
for k in os.listdir('testPictures'):
    if k.endswith('.jpg'):
        i = Image.open(k)
        kn, kext = os.path.splitext(k)
        print(kn)
```

by changing the directory to the name of the folder they are stored in (testPictures). However, I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MeisJeMetDeParel.jpg'
```

So it seems that the image within the folder is being accessed, as it has been able to identify the name of the first image in the folder, yet the code is unable to print the names of the images as it was able to do so when both the code and the images were saved together. What adjustments can I make to my code so that the pictures in the testPictures folder can be printed?
Thanks

Comment: Is this code running on Linux (or macOS) or Windows?

Comment: Windows 10 64 Bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os.listdir` function returns a path relative to the directory you specified so you have to `os.path.join` the directory to the name you got:

```
for k in os.listdir('testPictures'):
    if k.endswith('.jpg'):
        i = Image.open(os.path.join('testPictures', k))
        kn, kext = os.path.splitext(k)
        print(kn)
```

---

I might suggest that instead of calling `os.listdir` and checking the extension manually you could use the `glob` module instead and also avoid having to `os.path.join` the directory name:

```
import glob
for k in glob.glob('testPictures/*.jpg'):
    i = Image.open(k)
    kn, kext = os.path.splitext(k)
    print(kn)
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to do the trick, so thank you. Just a few other things: I'm wondering what the * in ('testPictures/*.jpg') is doing? I have used * before for removing the square brackets and quotation marks owhen printing items from an array. Another thing is the image names are being printed with 'testPictures' before each one, for example 'testPictures\StarryNight'. How would I be able to just display the file names? Thanks

Comment: Update, changed the print(kn) to print(kn[13:]) so that the 'testPicures\' before every file name isn't displayed. Is this acceptable or are there better ways to do this? Thanks

Comment: @tewi The `*` is a *wildcard*. `glob('testPictures/*.jpg')` will find all files under `testPictures` that end with `jpg`. The `*` means "anything" basically. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html#glob.glob) for more information

Comment: @tewi You can also use `os.basename` to remove the directory from a path. So `os.basename("/usr/local/bin/something.sh") == "something.sh"` or, if you are under windows, `os.basename("C://directory/file.bat") == "file.bat"`.

Comment: Great, very helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: @tewi I just realized I wrote it wrong in the comment. It's `os.path.basename`, not `os.basename`.